# Get attribute from string which mixes dots and indexing

Tags: python, getattr

I have a class with iterable attributes which themselves may have iterable attributes and so on to an arbitrary depth.

A simple example would be the following:

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = [Foo(), 4]

bar = Bar()
```

My goal is to get an attribute given its full name as a string, in the example, this could be `name = 'bar.c[0].a'`. In general, the name is longer and mixes `getattr`, list and dict indexing arbitrarily, e.g. something like `'a.b[0].c.d.e[5]['i'].f'`.

I know this could be achieved using `attr = eval(name)` but I want to avoid using `eval`. Without the indexing in between, I would just use `operator.attrgetter`. Is there a similarly clean and general solution for this problem?

Comment: If input is trusted then you may as well use eval, because this will be pretty much as difficult as writing a parser in the first place. If the data happens to be json-like, you may want to take a look at [`jq.py`](https://github.com/mwilliamson/jq.py) or [`pyjq`](https://github.com/doloopwhile/pyjq).

Comment: With a little work, you can parse the name into a list like `['a', 'b', '[0]', 'c', ...]`, which you could then turn into a list of `attrgetter` and `itemgetter` instances, which you can further compose into a single function using `functools.reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: g(f(x)), ...)`.

Comment: I don't know if there would be any significant benefit to do doing that rather than building a single value to query as @wim suggested.